# How to sort a google sheet Table Chart with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a table chart to automatically generate a dashboard, but when presented, the data is not sorted in the chart. I am trying to sort descending based on the second column in the chart. The documentation available on the apps scripts developers page is not particularly helpful about [implementation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-table-chart-builder#setinitialsortingdescendingcolumn). See below sample code & Error. Thanks!

TypeError: workingSheet.newChart(...).setChartType(...).addRange(...).addRange(...).setTransposeRowsAndColumns(...).setMergeStrategy(...).setInitialSortingDescending is not a function

```html
var chart = workingSheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)
    .addRange(tablePrice)
    .addRange(tableSubteam)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
    .setInitialSortingDescending(2)
    .setPosition(row2, col1, 0, 0)
    .build();
workingSheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script and error message, how about modifying as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
var chart = workingSheet.newChart()
    .asTableChart() // <--- Added
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)
    .addRange(tablePrice)
    .addRange(tableSubteam)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
    .setInitialSortingDescending(2)
    .setPosition(row2, col1, 0, 0)
    .build();
workingSheet.insertChart(chart);
```

#### Reference:

- [asTableChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#astablechart)